# Connecting to tor service in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, tor

My rest API URL is hosted in hidden service and is a .onion URL and I need to connect it from flutter app. I have tried [utopic_tor_onion_proxy](https://github.com/utopicnarwhal/utopic_tor_onion_proxy) but it is not working for me. Also I have tried [flutter_socks_proxy](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socks_proxy) which is great but only works for websockt connection not for HTTP request. How can I execute get/post request from onion URL?